# How did the bible and Chachamim know the time of Chatzot?

Tags: history, zemanim

In many places in the bible (e.g. [here](https://biblehub.com/text/psalms/119-62.htm)) as well as in the Mishna (e.g.[Berakhot 1,1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.1?lang=bi)) it's written that some things happened on [Chatzot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zmanim#Midnight) (midnight point-חצות הלילה) or some Mitzva should be done not late than Chatzot.

My question is how could people know then exactly when this time is? (there wasn't a clock in this time...)

Comment: What do you mean there wasn't a clock? People had ways of measuring time. Google history of horology for every timekeeping method imaginable.

Comment: Here's a simple contraption that could do it: take a big bucket, fill it with water, poke a small hole in the bottom so it drips, measure how much drips out between one sunrise and the next, put half that amount in the bucket at high noon, let it drip out. Midnight. I don't know if Moshe used this, but he totally could have.

Comment: Another possibility is to see when the zodiac opposite the current sign is highest in the sky. Depends how precise a calculation you need. I don't know if Moshe used this, but he totally could have.

Comment: (Notably, the most famous instance of midnight in Tanakh was on the 15th of the month when you could just check when the full moon is highest in the sky to calculate midnight. That's the trivial case. I don't know if Moshe used this, but he totally could have.)

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.3b.27?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en#13

Comment: @Dou sounds like you have an answer to post. Might I suggest you do so?

Comment: @msh210 I can't say if any of those methods were actually used.

Comment: 1. It appears that "חצות הלילה" in Exodus is the only mentioning of midnight and it says כ- meaning "around". 2. Another mentioning is in Tehhilim about David "חֲצוֹת־לַיְלָה אָקוּם לְהוֹדוֹת לָךְ עַל מִשְׁפְּטֵי צִדְקֶךָ׃" but the Gemmorah in Brochos says it was miraculous, David didn't know the time.

Comment: Thank you, but many of Halacha which were done before B.C. determined times for some of Mitzvas - until chatzot, it means they had some kind of accepted or common measurement method for that purpose.

Comment: @DoubleAA the question above is "how could people know" not "how did people know"

Comment: @Ubiquitous common? Most people said shema and went to sleep. It was not common to need to actually calculate when the last time was.